# writing to Binding inside a Button action triggers onDisappear

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have a struct:

```swift
struct Demo {
    struct Data {
        var value: Int
    }
    var data: [Data]
}
```

and then in some view I have:

```swift
struct SomeView: View {
    @Binding var demo: Demo
    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {
            demo.data[validIndex].value = 5
        }) {
           Image(systemName: "plus.circle")
                    .resizable()
                    .frame(width: 50.0, height: 50.0, alignment: .center)
        }
    }
}
```

assume the `var data: [Data]` has more than 5 elements in it, and we're just trying to update an existing value when we press this button in `SomeView`. If I use `SomeView` like this:

```
struct DisappearView: View {
    @Binding var demo: Demo

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
           // other views/shapes, etc
           SomeView(demo: $demo)
        }
        .onAppear {
          // do some stuff
        }
        .onDisappear {
         // do some stuff
        }
    }
}
```

The data comes from:

```
class DemoStore: ObservableObject {
    @Published var demos: [Demo] = []
    // assume this loads correctly and demos is populated

}
```

The access to `DemoStore` and `demos` getting passed around looks like this:

```
import SwiftUI

@main
struct App: App {
    @StateObject private var store = DemoStore()
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            NavigationView {
                DemosView(demos: $store.demos) { }
            }
        }
    }
}


struct DemosView: View {
    @Binding var demos: [Demo]

    var body: some View {
        List($demos) { $demo in
          NavigationLink(destination: DisappearView(demo: $demo)) {
               
          }
        }
     }
}
```

the write line, `demo.data[validIndex].value = 5` upon button press triggers the `.onDisappear` in the parent View, and I cannot figure out why. I've used the debugger to step through and execute the code line by line, the array update seems to work when I write it as an expression in the debugger, but if I resume the code it boots out of the view and triggers `.onDisappear`. If I comment out the write line, `.onDisappear` isn't triggered when I press the button.

Comment: Show a place where DisappearView is created and where is source of truth that `demo` is bound to.

Comment: Yes, @Mike Lyons, you need to show DisappearView and "demo" value